# ImportError: No module named _cvblob python

Tags: python, ubuntu

Can any one tell me why am i getting this error while tying to run the python cvblob example shown [in this page](http://github.com/oostendo/cvblob-python)
error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "test.py", line 4, in <module>
import cvblob
 File "/home/sabrine/cvblob/python/cvblob/__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
from _cvblob import *
ImportError: No module named _cvblob
```

Comment: missing `_cvblob.so` file?  You need to compile `_cvblob.C` and make `_cvblob.so`

Comment: @ Kenji Noguchi How can i do so??!

Comment: Read the installation instruction at the github

Comment: @ Kenji Noguchi i did and i followed it step by step but still getting the same result besides i didn't understand what should i edit when the author said './build.sh (you may need to edit if you have a different python than 2.6)' cause i do work with python 2.7

Answer (score 1):

```
from cvblob import *
```

not `from _cvblob`

Comment: he did `import cvblob`.  nothing wrong with that.  The `__init__.py` is trying to import from `_cvblob`.

Answer (score 0):

I found that the problem was in edditing the `build.sh` by changing the version of python inside,the new file look like this :

```
g++ -fPIC -I/usr/include/python2.7 -I/usr/include -I/usr/local/include -c _cvblob.C
g++ -shared -Wall _cvblob.o -L/usr/lib -L/usr/local/lib -lopencv_core -lcvblob    -lboost_python -L/usr/lib/python2.7/config -lpython2.7 -o _cvblob.so
```